# Adding Stripe payment data to a Multi Part Wizard form in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, forms, stripe-payments

I'm trying to create a three page wizard in angular JS, with the final part taking payment details.

However, looking through the Stripe docs I notice that there are no name attributes on any of the form elements related to Stripe.

At the moment I'm using buttons to link to the next step in the wizard, and only have a single form, which is submitted together. The three page wizard is based on this tutorial:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-multi-step-form-using-ui-router

as you can see i'm using:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
    <a ui-sref="form.payment" class="btn btn-danger">
    Next Section <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

to navigate to the next form page.

My question is - how can i submit both the objects bound to the model (formData), *and* the Stripe data from within the same form. Is this possible?
If so - how can i do this and still keep the wizard functionality?

Below is my controller:

```
angular.module('formApp')
.controller('formController', ['$scope', 'Appointment', function($scope, Appointment) {

    // we will store all of our form data in this object
    $scope.formData = {};
    $scope.formData.appintment_date = "";
    $scope.opened        = false;
    /*$scope.momentDate = moment($scope.formData.date);*/
    $scope.time1 = new Date();
    $scope.showMeridian = true;
    //Datepicker
    $scope.dateOptions = {
        'year-format': "'yy'",
        'show-weeks' : false, 
        'show-time':true
    };

    // function to process the form
    $scope.processForm = function() {
            console.log($scope.formData);
         var date = moment($scope.formData.date).format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a");
            /*console.log(date);*/
            var app = new Appointment($scope.formData);
            //console.log(app);
            app.$save();
    };
}]);
```

home.html

```
<div class="page-header text-center">           
                        <!-- the links to our nested states using relative paths -->
                        <!-- add the active class if the state matches our ui-sref -->
                        <div id="status-buttons" class="text-center">
                            <a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".date"><span>1</span> Date</a>
                            <a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".address"><span>2</span> Address</a>
                            <a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".payment"><span>3</span> Payment</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
<!-- use ng-submit to catch the form submission and use our Angular function -->
            <form id="signup-form" ng-submit="processForm()">
              <!-- our nested state views will be injected here -->
               <div id="form-views" ui-view></div>
            </form>
```

form-interests.html

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" ng-model="formData.name" required>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" ng-model="formData.email" required>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Address</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" ng-model="formData.address_1" placeholder="e.g. Unit and Street"required>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" ng-model="formData.city" placeholder="City e.g. Toronto">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" ng-model="formData.postcode" placeholder="Postal Code" required>

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Phone Number</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" ng-model="formData.phone" placeholder="(416) - 222 5555"required>

</div>

<div class="form-group row">
<div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">

    <a ui-sref="form.payment" class="btn btn-danger">
    Next Section <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right"></span>
    </a>
</div>
</div>
```

form-payment.html - note the lack of name attributes.

```
<!-- form-payment.html -->
  <span class="payment-errors"></span>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="card_number">Card Number</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" size="20" data-stripe="number"/>
    </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <label for="CVC"> CVC</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" size="4" data-stripe="cvc"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <label for="exp_month"> Expiration (Month)</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" size="2" data-stripe="exp-month"/>
 <label for="exp_month"> Expiration (Year)</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" size="4" data-stripe="exp-year"/>
  </div>
<div class="text-center">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>
    <h3>Thanks For Your Money!</h3>
    <button type="submit" id="submitButton" class="btn">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: The lack of name attribute here is to make sure those data are not posted to your server along with the form as you should not post the card details to your server.

Comment: thanks koopajah - i understand the reason for the lack of attribute - but how can I solve my problem?

Comment: If you want to update $scope.formData with the input value of form-payment, just use ng-model in the input elements of form-payment.

The sample of Card Number will be like this.

<input type="text" class="form-control" size="20" data-stripe="number" ng-model="formData.cardnumber" />

Comment: hi Yazaki - thanks for this - my concern about this is compliance. I'm not keep for the card number to hit my server, and as I understand Stripe forms dont normally do that - instead they will process the form through a jquery processor that returns the Token - if i do this as part of my controller then I'm still handling the card data